# Meaning of "to hear the rollers thunder" lyrics in "Privateering"by Mark Knopfler

Tags: lyrics, meaning

I was listening to Mark Knopfler's song "Privateering" from 2012 album under the same name and and I am intrigued by lyrics line I do not understand. The song tells about a life of a [privateer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privateer), a civil sailor or a pirate authorised by a government to attack foreign vessels during wartime. The chorus goes:

> To lay with pretty women
>
> To drink Madeira wine
>
> **To hear the rollers thunder**
>
> On a shore that isn't mine

I do not understand what thundering rollers are. Is it a reference to some kind of loud harbour equipment (e.g. rollers used to move heavy loads), some type of war equipment (e.g. artillery) or am I missing the reference completely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Roller*** seems to be a way to describe a **type of wave**; the thunder is the sound as they break on the shore.

An account from the Surgeon of *H.M.S. Chanticleer*, 1829:

> One of the most interesting phenomena at Ascension are the rollers; in
>   other words, a heavy swell producing high surf on the leeward shores
>   of the island, occurring without any apparent cause. All is tranquil
>   in the distance, the sea-breeze scarcely ripples the surface of water,
>   when a high swelling wave is suddenly observed rolling towards the
>   island. At first it appears to move slowly forward, till at length it
>   breaks on the outer reefs. The swell then increases, wave urges on
>   wave, until it reaches the beach, where it bursts with tremendous
>   fury.

*Manual of Meteorology*, Napier Shaw, p 17.

Less poetically, from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roller :

> A long heavy sea wave as it advances towards the shore.

Comment: Thanks, the lyrics make much more sense now :)

Comment: @Klara it's always nice to be able to sing along without thinking "what does that mean...?". Knopfler has so many great stories and images in his songs!

Answer (score 3):

Rollers is commonly used to describe waves that break along the length of the beach. Usually it isn't used to refer to large, surfable waves, but those a bit smaller - those producing a sound that does sound a lot like thunder, especially on a long beach.

Answer (score 2):

I actually think the "rollers" are the cannons on wheels that roll back on recoil - not waves.  When you "...hear the rollers' thunder on a shore that isn't mine", it's cannon fire on foreign soil.  Waves can occur on any shore including your own.